# How to make the connection of dynamixel become modular by using ros2 control hardware interface

Tags: ros2, c++, dynamixel, hardware-interface, ros2-control

I'm trying to make the robot that using dynamixels to control the movement of the joint. One of the application is that when one leg of the robot is disconnected, when I connect it again the software should detect and the leg should be able to move again without restarting or run any other codes. I use ros2 control foxy to control it and connect the hardware via the interface from follwing [URL](https://github.com/dynamixel-community/dynamixel_hardware/tree/foxy). My own code is shown below. I'm not familiar with c++ so I'm not sure how to add that feature to the code. From my side I think I should edit somewhere around the place that use pinging function from dynamixel workbench `dynamixel_workbench_.ping()` from line 84.

```
#include "dynamixel_hardware/dynamixel_hardware.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_return_values.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

namespace dynamixel_hardware
{
constexpr const char * kDynamixelHardware = "DynamixelHardware";
constexpr uint8_t kGoalPositionIndex = 0;
constexpr uint8_t kGoalVelocityIndex = 1;
constexpr uint8_t kPresentPositionVelocityCurrentIndex = 0;
constexpr const char * kGoalPositionItem = "Goal_Position";
constexpr const char * kGoalVelocityItem = "Goal_Velocity";
constexpr const char * kMovingSpeedItem = "Moving_Speed";
constexpr const char * kPresentPositionItem = "Present_Position";
constexpr const char * kPresentVelocityItem = "Present_Velocity";
constexpr const char * kPresentSpeedItem = "Present_Speed";
constexpr const char * kPresentCurrentItem = "Present_Current";
constexpr const char * kPresentLoadItem = "Present_Load";

return_type DynamixelHardware::configure(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info)
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "configure");
  if (configure_default(info) != return_type::OK) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  joints_.resize(info_.joints.size(), Joint());
  joint_ids_.resize(info_.joints.size(), 0);

  for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); i++) {
    joint_ids_[i] = std::stoi(info_.joints[i].parameters.at("id"));
    joints_[i].state.position = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    joints_[i].state.velocity = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    joints_[i].state.effort = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    joints_[i].command.position = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    joints_[i].command.velocity = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    joints_[i].command.effort = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "joint_id %d: %d", i, joint_ids_[i]);
  }

  if (
    info_.hardware_parameters.find("use_dummy") != info_.hardware_parameters.end() &&
    info_.hardware_parameters.at("use_dummy") == "true") {
    use_dummy_ = true;
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "dummy mode");
    status_ = hardware_interface::status::CONFIGURED;
    return return_type::OK;
  }

  auto usb_port = info_.hardware_parameters.at("usb_port");
  auto baud_rate = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters.at("baud_rate"));
  const char * log = nullptr;

  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "usb_port: %s", usb_port.c_str());
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "baud_rate: %d", baud_rate);

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.init(usb_port.c_str(), baud_rate, &log)) {
    RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  // for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); ++i) {
  //   uint16_t model_number = 0;
  //   if (!dynamixel_workbench_.ping(joint_ids_[i], &model_number, &log)) {
  //     RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
  //     return return_type::ERROR;
  //   }
  // }

  std::vector<uint8_t> connected_joint_ids;
  std::vector<uint16_t> connected_model_numbers;

  // for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); ++i) {
  //   uint16_t model_number = 0;
    
  //   // Attempt to ping the joint
  //   if (dynamixel_workbench_.ping(joint_ids_[i], &model_number, &log)) {
  //       // Joint is responsive, add it to the list of connected joints
  //       connected_joint_ids.push_back(joint_ids_[i]);
  //       connected_model_numbers.push_back(model_number);
  //   } else {
  //       // Joint is not responsive, log an error but continue
  //       RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Failed to ping joint ID %d: %s", joint_ids_[i], log);
  //   }
  // }

  std::vector<bool> is_connected(info_joints.size());

  // while(! is_connected) {
  //   for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); ++i) {
  //     uint16_t model_number = 0;
  //     if (dynamixel_workbench_.ping(joint_ids_[i], &model_number, &log)) {
  //     }
  //   }
  // }
  

  enable_torque(false);
  set_control_mode(ControlMode::Velocity, true);
  enable_torque(true);

  const ControlItem * goal_position =
    dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kGoalPositionItem);
  if (goal_position == nullptr) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  const ControlItem * goal_velocity =
    dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kGoalVelocityItem);
  if (goal_velocity == nullptr) {
    goal_velocity = dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kMovingSpeedItem);
  }
  if (goal_velocity == nullptr) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  const ControlItem * present_position =
    dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kPresentPositionItem);
  if (present_position == nullptr) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  const ControlItem * present_velocity =
    dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kPresentVelocityItem);
  if (present_velocity == nullptr) {
    present_velocity = dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kPresentSpeedItem);
  }
  if (present_velocity == nullptr) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  const ControlItem * present_current =
    dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kPresentCurrentItem);
  if (present_current == nullptr) {
    present_current = dynamixel_workbench_.getItemInfo(joint_ids_[0], kPresentLoadItem);
  }
  if (present_current == nullptr) {
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  control_items_[kGoalPositionItem] = goal_position;
  control_items_[kGoalVelocityItem] = goal_velocity;
  control_items_[kPresentPositionItem] = present_position;
  control_items_[kPresentVelocityItem] = present_velocity;
  control_items_[kPresentCurrentItem] = present_current;

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.addSyncWriteHandler(
        control_items_[kGoalPositionItem]->address, control_items_[kGoalPositionItem]->data_length,
        &log)) {
    RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.addSyncWriteHandler(
        control_items_[kGoalVelocityItem]->address, control_items_[kGoalVelocityItem]->data_length,
        &log)) {
    RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  uint16_t start_address = std::min(
    control_items_[kPresentPositionItem]->address, control_items_[kPresentCurrentItem]->address);
  uint16_t read_length = control_items_[kPresentPositionItem]->data_length +
                         control_items_[kPresentVelocityItem]->data_length +
                         control_items_[kPresentCurrentItem]->data_length + 2;
  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.addSyncReadHandler(start_address, read_length, &log)) {
    RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  status_ = hardware_interface::status::CONFIGURED;
  return return_type::OK;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> DynamixelHardware::export_state_interfaces()
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "export_state_interfaces");
  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;
  for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); i++) {
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &joints_[i].state.position));
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &joints_[i].state.velocity));
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_EFFORT, &joints_[i].state.effort));
  }

  return state_interfaces;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> DynamixelHardware::export_command_interfaces()
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "export_command_interfaces");
  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;
  for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); i++) {
    command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &joints_[i].command.position));
    command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &joints_[i].command.velocity));
  }

  return command_interfaces;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::start()
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "start");
  for (uint i = 0; i < joints_.size(); i++) {
    if (use_dummy_ && std::isnan(joints_[i].state.position)) {
      joints_[i].state.position = 0.0;
      joints_[i].state.velocity = 0.0;
      joints_[i].state.effort = 0.0;
    }
  }
  read();
  reset_command();
  write();

  status_ = hardware_interface::status::STARTED;
  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::stop()
{
  RCLCPP_DEBUG(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "stop");
  status_ = hardware_interface::status::STOPPED;
  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::read()
{
  if (use_dummy_) {
    return return_type::OK;
  }

  std::vector<uint8_t> ids(info_.joints.size(), 0);
  std::vector<int32_t> positions(info_.joints.size(), 0);
  std::vector<int32_t> velocities(info_.joints.size(), 0);
  std::vector<int32_t> currents(info_.joints.size(), 0);

  std::copy(joint_ids_.begin(), joint_ids_.end(), ids.begin());
  const char * log = nullptr;

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.syncRead(
        kPresentPositionVelocityCurrentIndex, ids.data(), ids.size(), &log)) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
  }

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.getSyncReadData(
        kPresentPositionVelocityCurrentIndex, ids.data(), ids.size(),
        control_items_[kPresentCurrentItem]->address,
        control_items_[kPresentCurrentItem]->data_length, currents.data(), &log)) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
  }

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.getSyncReadData(
        kPresentPositionVelocityCurrentIndex, ids.data(), ids.size(),
        control_items_[kPresentVelocityItem]->address,
        control_items_[kPresentVelocityItem]->data_length, velocities.data(), &log)) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
  }

  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.getSyncReadData(
        kPresentPositionVelocityCurrentIndex, ids.data(), ids.size(),
        control_items_[kPresentPositionItem]->address,
        control_items_[kPresentPositionItem]->data_length, positions.data(), &log)) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
  }

  for (uint i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
    joints_[i].state.position = dynamixel_workbench_.convertValue2Radian(ids[i], positions[i]);
    joints_[i].state.velocity = dynamixel_workbench_.convertValue2Velocity(ids[i], velocities[i]);
    joints_[i].state.effort = dynamixel_workbench_.convertValue2Current(currents[i]);
  }

  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::write()
{
  if (use_dummy_) {
    for (auto & joint : joints_) {
      joint.state.position = joint.command.position;
    }

    return return_type::OK;
  }

  std::vector<uint8_t> ids(info_.joints.size(), 0);
  std::vector<int32_t> commands(info_.joints.size(), 0);

  std::copy(joint_ids_.begin(), joint_ids_.end(), ids.begin());
  const char * log = nullptr;

  if (std::any_of(
        joints_.cbegin(), joints_.cend(), [](auto j) { return j.command.velocity != 0.0; })) {
    // Velocity control
    set_control_mode(ControlMode::Velocity);
    for (uint i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
      commands[i] = dynamixel_workbench_.convertVelocity2Value(
        ids[i], static_cast<float>(joints_[i].command.velocity));
    }
    if (!dynamixel_workbench_.syncWrite(
          kGoalVelocityIndex, ids.data(), ids.size(), commands.data(), 1, &log)) {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
    }
    return return_type::OK;
  } else if (std::any_of(
               joints_.cbegin(), joints_.cend(), [](auto j) { return j.command.effort != 0.0; })) {
    // Effort control
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Effort control is not implemented");
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  // Position control
  set_control_mode(ControlMode::Position);
  for (uint i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
    commands[i] = dynamixel_workbench_.convertRadian2Value(
      ids[i], static_cast<float>(joints_[i].command.position));
  }
  if (!dynamixel_workbench_.syncWrite(
        kGoalPositionIndex, ids.data(), ids.size(), commands.data(), 1, &log)) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
  }

  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::enable_torque(const bool enabled)
{
  const char * log = nullptr;

  if (enabled && !torque_enabled_) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); ++i) {
      if (!dynamixel_workbench_.torqueOn(joint_ids_[i], &log)) {
        RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
        return return_type::ERROR;
      }
    }
    reset_command();
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Torque enabled");
  } else if (!enabled && torque_enabled_) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < info_.joints.size(); ++i) {
      if (!dynamixel_workbench_.torqueOff(joint_ids_[i], &log)) {
        RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
        return return_type::ERROR;
      }
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Torque disabled");
  }

  torque_enabled_ = enabled;
  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::set_control_mode(const ControlMode & mode, const bool force_set)
{
  const char * log = nullptr;

  if (mode == ControlMode::Velocity && (force_set || control_mode_ != ControlMode::Velocity)) {
    bool torque_enabled = torque_enabled_;
    if (torque_enabled) {
      enable_torque(false);
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < joint_ids_.size(); ++i) {
      if (!dynamixel_workbench_.setVelocityControlMode(joint_ids_[i], &log)) {
        RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
        return return_type::ERROR;
      }
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Velocity control");
    control_mode_ = ControlMode::Velocity;

    if (torque_enabled) {
      enable_torque(true);
    }
  } else if (
    mode == ControlMode::Position && (force_set || control_mode_ != ControlMode::Position)) {
    bool torque_enabled = torque_enabled_;
    if (torque_enabled) {
      enable_torque(false);
    }

    for (uint i = 0; i < joint_ids_.size(); ++i) {
      if (!dynamixel_workbench_.setPositionControlMode(joint_ids_[i], &log)) {
        RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "%s", log);
        return return_type::ERROR;
      }
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Position control");
    control_mode_ = ControlMode::Position;

    if (torque_enabled) {
      enable_torque(true);
    }
  } else if (control_mode_ != ControlMode::Velocity && control_mode_ != ControlMode::Position) {
    RCLCPP_FATAL(
      rclcpp::get_logger(kDynamixelHardware), "Only position/velocity control are implemented");
    return return_type::ERROR;
  }

  return return_type::OK;
}

return_type DynamixelHardware::reset_command()
{
  for (uint i = 0; i < joints_.size(); i++) {
    joints_[i].command.position = joints_[i].state.position;
    joints_[i].command.velocity = 0.0;
    joints_[i].command.effort = 0.0;
  }

  return return_type::OK;
}

}  // namespace dynamixel_hardware

#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(dynamixel_hardware::DynamixelHardware, hardware_interface::SystemInterface)
```

Comment: As this is a very vendor-specific question, maybe you should ask in the github repository of dynamixel.